# Use PHP's preg_replace() to return only the value inside the <h1>?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

How would I use PHP's `preg_replace()` to return only the value inside the `<h1>` in the following string (it's HTML text loaded in a variable called `$html`):

```
<h1>I'm Header</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tincidunt porttitor magna, quis molestie augue sagittis quis.</p>

<p>Pellentesque tincidunt porttitor magna, quis molestie augue sagittis quis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

I've tried this: `preg_replace('#<h1>([.*])</h1>.*#', '$1', $html)`, but to no avail. Am I regex-ing this correctly? And is there a better PHP function that I should be using instead of `preg_replace`?

Comment: Umm...just a bit of sidebar topic here: as I was typing this post (most of the way through), a weird unicorn graphic showed up on the right side of the page and, like MS Clippy, asked me if I wanted help parsing XML, and then sent me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 When I came back to my post to take a screenshot of the unicorn, it was gone. Somebody please tell me that wasn't a hallucination. Somebody? Anybody? Hello?

Comment: that wasn't hallucination, and generally you shouldn't want parsing HTML with regexes

Comment: No hallucination. That's good. So... what what it???

Comment: it was a link to a thread that explains that generally you shouldn't parse HTML using regular expressions

Comment: Haha! Okay... but why the unicorn???

Comment: @Sam You must be new here... :-3

Comment: Maybe check what date you saw the unicorn? ;)

Comment: [I want this unicorn as a regular feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127823/please-keep-the-aprils-1st-unicorn-for-parse-html-using-regex-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you do it using `preg_replace`:

```
$header = preg_replace('/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>.*/iU', '$1', $html);
```

You can also use `preg_match`:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/<h1>(.*)</h1>.*/iU', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: `.*` in the end is harmful - it would cut all the other text off

Comment: but he wants to get only the h1 tag contents...he does not care about the rest.

Comment: Oh, yes. It wouldn't destroy the data, but still pointless ;-)

Comment: @TamikSoziev This is close. When I echo($header) I get the contents of the <h1> successfully, but the rest of the HTML is there too. I just want to extract the guts of the <h1>.

Comment: WooHoo!!! preg_match() did it! In an effort to make me a better regexer, can you explain the "iU" part? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`([.*])` means `dot OR astersk`

What you need is `(.*?)`, which means any amount of any characters ungreedy

or

`([^<]*)` - which means any amount of any characters but not `<`